# In Main function..Average is not displayed. Thread is not alive but not terminated. why?

Tags: java

I wanted to created a program to calculate average of the numbers input through console using threading in java. In the main function I never get the output of the average value from the function getAverage(). What's wrong..When I debug..program terminates but in normal run..It should terminate when I enter anything other than double value but it does not happen.

```
import java.util.*;
public class P1
{
    private AverageCalculator ac; 
    private boolean stop;

    public Thread inputThread,averageThread;

    public P1()
    {
        ac = new AverageCalculator();
        new UserInteraction(ac);
        new ToAverage(ac);
    }

    public void printAverage()
    {
        System.out.println("Average is " + ac.getAverage());
    }

    private class AverageCalculator{
        private double average=0,sum=0;
        private int i=0;
        private boolean flag=false;

        private double getAverage()
        {
            return average;
        }

        private synchronized void sum(double val) {
            while(flag) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch(InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("Thread Interrputed"); }
            }
            sum += val;
            i++;
            flag = true;
            notify();
        }

        private synchronized void calculateAverage()
        {
            while(!flag) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch(InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("thread interrupted"); }
            }
            average = (sum / i);
            flag = false;
            notify();
        }
    }

    private class UserInteraction implements Runnable {
        private AverageCalculator ac;
        //private boolean take=true;
        private double input=0;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        private UserInteraction(AverageCalculator ac) {
            this.ac = ac;
            inputThread = new Thread(this,"Input thread");
            inputThread.start();
            stop=false;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number: ");

            while(!stop) {
                if(s.hasNextDouble() == false) {
                    stop = true;
                    s.close();
                }
                else
                {

                    input = s.nextDouble();
                    s.nextLine();

                    ac.sum(input);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ToAverage implements Runnable {
        private AverageCalculator ac;

        private ToAverage(AverageCalculator ac)
        {
            this.ac = ac;
            averageThread = new Thread(this,"Average doer Thread");
            averageThread.start();
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while(!stop) {

                ac.calculateAverage();
            }
        }
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
        P1 p = new P1();
        try
        {
            p.inputThread.join();
            p.averageThread.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) { System.out.println("Interrupted in Main"); }
        System.out.println("Thread input alive check: " + p.inputThread.isAlive());
        System.out.println("Thread average alive check: " + p.averageThread.isAlive());
        p.printAverage();
    }
}
```

Comment: please add only minimal code to recreate problem. not whole code

Comment: Ok thanks.. I will..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not totally debug your code, but the issue is that you're calling `wait()`.  This method puts your threads into wait state and a call to `notify()` or `notifyAll()` must occur to wake your threads up.

Here is a decent explanation of what is happening when the `wait()` method is called:
[Difference Between Wait and Sleep in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-and-sleep)

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. It is the wait method that is causing the second thread to keep waiting even when the logic says top now..it keeps waiting.